# SignalR hub Clients object disposed

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I have the following SignalR Hub with in-memory connection management.

```
[Authorize]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private static readonly ConnectionMapping<string> _connections =
        new ConnectionMapping<string>();

    private readonly IMessageRepository _messagesRepository;

    public ChatHub(IMessageRepository messageRepository)
    {
        _messagesRepository = messagesRepository;
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);

        //await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "SignalR Users");
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        _connections.Remove(name, Context.ConnectionId);

        //await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "SignalR Users");
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }

    public async void SendMessage(ChatMessage chatMessage)
    {
        var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        var chatHistoryMessage = await _messagesRepository.SaveMessageAsync(chatMessage);

        var availableConnections = _connections.GetConnections(name);

        if (availableConnections.Any())
        {
            foreach (var connectionId in availableConnections)
            {
                Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", chatHistoryMessage);
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

However, when executing the code the following line

```
Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", 1);
```

raises an object disposed error on `Clients`.

This issue started happening when I added the repository line:

```
var chatHistoryMessage = await _messagesRepository.SaveMessageAsync(chatMessage);
```

SaveMessageAsync method:

```
public async Task<ChatHistory> SaveMessageAsync (ChatMessage chatMessage)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnProvider.ConnectionString))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                return (await conn.QueryAsync<ChatHistory>("[mob].[spSaveChatMessage]",
                    new
                    {
                       ..
                    },
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
```

Why would my `Clients` object be disposed? If I wait with the debugger that issue never happens.

Comment: `SendMessage` shouldn't be an `async void`, use `async Task`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

Comment: That solved it. I did not have it as async before adding the repository line and I just added the async keyword. Was the disposed object happening because SignalR wasn't aware of my method - it being void?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `SendMessage` method should be an `async Task` rather than an `async void`.

The issue could be caused by the way the SignalR framework runs `async void`s.

See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) for a good overview.

> Async methods returning void don’t provide an easy way to notify the
>   calling code that they’ve completed.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. The issue was resolved.